# How to hide wordpress post comment form for specific role

Tags: comments, forms

How to hide "comment_form();" for Author role in wordpress? What i need to add in comments.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook to the `comments_open` filter.

```
add_filter('comments_open', function($open, $post_id){
  if(in_array( 'author', (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles){
    return false;
  }
  return $open;
}, 10, 2);
```